# Is it possible to toggle a certain step in sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I wonder if we can set up an "optional" step in `sklearn.pipeline`. For example, for a classification problem, I may want to try an `ExtraTreesClassifier` with AND without a `PCA` transformation ahead of it. In practice, it might be a pipeline with an extra parameter specifying the toggle of the `PCA` step, so that I can optimize on it via `GridSearch` and etc. I don't see such an implementation in sklearn source, but is there any work-around?

Furthermore, since the possible parameter values of a following step in pipeline might depend on the parameters in a previous step (e.g., valid values of `ExtraTreesClassifier.max_features` depend on `PCA.n_components`), is it possible to specify such a conditional dependency in `sklearn.pipeline` and `sklearn.grid_search`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `Pipeline` steps cannot currently be made optional in a grid search but you could wrap the `PCA` class into your own `OptionalPCA` component with a boolean parameter to turn off PCA when requested as a quick workaround. You might want to have a look at [hyperopt](https://github.com/jaberg/hyperopt) to setup more complex search spaces. I think it has good sklearn integration to support this kind of patterns by default but I cannot find the doc anymore. Maybe have a look at [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mp1xnPfE4PY).
- For the dependent parameters problem, `GridSearchCV` supports trees of parameters to handle this case [as demonstrated in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#exhaustive-grid-search).

Comment: As a side remark, note that `ExtraTreesClassifier.max_features` can be a float value between 0.0 and 1.0, instead of an integer value. This is useful when the actual number of features variable, as in your case.

Answer (score 20):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#usage):

> Individual steps may also be replaced as parameters, and non-final
>   steps may be ignored by setting them to None:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
params = dict(reduce_dim=[None, PCA(5), PCA(10)],
              clf=[SVC(), LogisticRegression()],
              clf__C=[0.1, 10, 100])
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params)
```

Comment: Most recent documentation states that you should ignore non-final steps with the string `'passthrough'` instead of `None`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html