# Including Scaling and PCA as parameter of GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, pipeline, grid-search

I want to run a logistic regression using `GridSearchCV`, but I want to contrast the performance when Scaling and PCA is used, so I don't want to use it in all cases.

I basically would like to include PCA and Scaling as "parameters" of the `GridSearchCV`

I am aware I can make a pipeline like this:

```
mnl = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, multi_class="multinomial")

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('mnl', mnl)])

params_mnl = {'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
              'mnl__max_iter':[500,1000,2000,3000]}
```

The thing is that, in this case, the scaling would be applied in all folds, right?
Is there a way to make it so it's "included" in the gridsearch?

EDIT:

I just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366561/use-sklearns-gridsearchcv-with-a-pipeline-preprocessing-just-once) and even though it's similar to what I want, it's not really it, because in that case the Scaler will be applied to the best estimator out of the GridSearch.

What I want to do is, for example, let's say

```
params_mnl = {'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs']}
```

I want to run the regression with Scaler+newton-cg, No Scaler+newton-cg, Scaler+lbfgs, No Scaler+lbfgs.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/19262621/10495893

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up the parameters `with_mean` and `with_std` of `StandardScaler()` as False to represent no standerdization. In the `GirdSearchCV`, the parameter `para_grid` can be set up as

```
param_grid = [{'scale__with_mean': [False],
               'scale__with_std': [False],
               'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
               'mnl__max_iter':[500,1000,2000,3000]
              },
              {'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
              'mnl__max_iter':[500,1000,2000,3000]}
]
```

Then the first dict in the list is "No Scaler+mnl" and the second is "Scaler+mnl"

Ref:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/putting_together.html

Edit:
I think it's complicated if you also considering turn on/off PCA... Maybe you need to define a customised PCA which derives the original PCA. And then define additional boolean argument which determines whether the PCA should be executed or not...

```
class MYPCA(PCA):
    def __init__(self, PCA_turn_on, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.PCA_turn_on = PCA_turn_on
    
    def fit(X, y=None):
        if (PCA_turn_on == True):
            return super().fit(X, y=None)
        else:
            pass

    # same for other methods defined in PCA
```

Comment: that looks good! Thanks! Do you have any idea for the PCA tho? I couldn't find any parameter in it that could be set to False or anything

Comment: actually, I realized it's a bit more complicated than that. To use PCA I need to scale the data, so I would need for the case with PCA to be with Scaling as well, necessarily

Comment: I also think it's complicated... Maybe you need to define a customised PCA which derives the original PCA. And then define additional boolean argument which determines whether the PCA should be executed or not...

Comment: Tried doing what I could... even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266737/parallel-pipeline-to-get-best-model-using-gridsearch) answer and it didn't quite do it... unfortunately I dont have much time to figure it out, so I'll do two grid searches, one with pca and one without, and then get the best model between the two

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for `Pipeline`:

> A step’s estimator may be replaced entirely by setting the parameter with its name to another estimator, or a transformer removed by setting it to ‘passthrough’ or `None`.

For example:

```py
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('mnl', mnl),
])

params = {
    'scale': ['passthrough', StandardScaler()],
    'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
    'mnl__max_iter': [500, 1000, 2000, 3000],
}
```